# How can I explicitly convert this derived class in .NET 2?

Tags: .net, generics, inheritance, .net-2.0, derived-class

I can't seem to find out how to do this in `.NET2.0` despite searching Google and SO.

Say I have the following classes:

```
public class Fruit {
    prop string Color {get; set;}
}

public class Apple : Fruit {
    public Apple() {
        this.Color = "Red";
    }
}

public class Grape: Fruit {
    public Grape() {
        this.Color = "Green";
    }
}
```

Now I want to do this:

```
public List<Fruit> GetFruit() {
    List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();
    // .. populate list ..
    return list;
}    


List<Grape> grapes = GetFruit();
```

But of course I get `Cannot implicitly convert type Fruit to Grape`.

I realize this is because I could really mess things up if I did:

```
List<Grape> list = new List<Grape>();
list.add(new Apple());
```

Because while both are `Fruit`, an `Apple` isn't a `Grape`.  So that makes sense.

But I don't understand why I can't do this:

```
List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();
list.add(new Apple());
list.add(new Grape());
```

At the very least, I need to be able to:

```
List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();
list.add(new Apple());   // will always be Apple
list.add(new Apple());   // will always be Apple
list.add(new Apple());   // will always be Apple
```

Any ideas on how to do this in `.NET2`?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry, I was mistaken.  I can in fact do:

```
List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();
list.add(new Apple());
list.add(new Grape());
```

The `.FindAll` and `.Convert` did the trick.

Comment: `prop string Color {get; set;}` prop ?

Comment: "But I don't understand why I can't do this" - So far as I'm aware, you should be able to do that (assuming you correct the case of `Add` and make `Fruit` compilable)

Comment: "But I don't understand why I can't do this:" - you can, as long as you use `Add` instead of `add` (which doesn't exist); all the examples at the end are fine.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right... I've tried it on .NET 2.0 to make 100% sure it works and it does

Comment: @asawyer yeah.  I typed 'prop' because that's a shortcut on Visual Studio.  lol.  I'm so used to typing that it came out without thinking.  lol  And marc and paolo.  You were both correct.  I **can** do that.  That was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you need something specific in `.Net 2.0` first I would filter each using [FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh1w7y8z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) then use [ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
List<Grape> grapes = list
  .FindAll(delegate(Fruit f) { return f is Grape; })
  .ConvertAll<Grape>(delegate(Fruit f) { return f as Grape; });
```

As for your questions:

> But I don't understand why I can't do this:

```
List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();
list.Add(new Apple());
list.Add(new Grape());
```

You can do this, it is completely valid, did you mistype something (add vs Add)?

Comment: I was wrong about not being able to insert a grape and apple.  Your FindAll and ConvertAll suggestion seems to be the way to go for my needs.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am 100% sure you can do this:

```
List<Fruit> list = new List<Fruit>();
list.add(new Apple());
list.add(new Grape());
```

Is there a particular reason why you want to stick to .net 2.0?

Using .net 3.5 you would have two possibilities:

```
List<Apple> apples = list.OfType<Apple>().ToList();
```

This would filter your list and return a list of apples.
You have also:

```
List<Apple> apples = list.Cast<Apple>().ToList();
```

Which would not filter but assume all elements in the list are apples (and throw and InvalidCastException if not).

Comment: I have to stick to .net 2 because this is a legacy GUI application that can not be upgraded.  Most of the machines it runs on are still running XP with .net 2.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are never covariant, even in later versions of .NET (enumerables are).

The `list.Add(new Apple())` etc should already work fine - there's no problem with that.

For the assignment, you might have to do something like:

```
List<Grape> grapes = GetFruit().ConvertAll(x => (Grape)x);
```

or on older compilers:

```
List<Grape> grapes = GetFruit().ConvertAll<Grape>(delegate(Fruit x) {
    return (Grape)x;
});
```

(which is semantically identical)

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that grapes will return only `Grape` objects, you can use LINQ Cast:

[Enumerable.Cast Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb341406.aspx)

```
List<Garapes> grapes = GetFruit().Cast<Grape>().ToList();
```

You could also use LINQ `Where` to take only the fruits which are grapes, before making the conversion

`Where(f => f is Grape)`